# Regex comma separated list contains nine digits phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I have quite small but very annoying problem with regex. I would like to find regex for comma separated list which contains nine digits phone number for example :

Pass : 123456789,123456789

Not Pass : 123456789,123456789,

So far, I have something like this :`/^\d{9}+(,\d{9}\+)\*$/` Of course it works for example in this tool [http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/), but in javascript it does not work and I get this I suppose well known error (for Javascript people) :

```
Invalid regular expression: /^\d{9}+(,\d{9}\+)\*$/: Nothing to repeat
```

So, I added backslash and it looks like this one : `/^\d{9}\+(,\d{9}\+)\*$/`. Of course this one also does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are escaping `*`,`+` with `\`.That is the problem..

`*` means match the preceding char 0 to many times

`+` means match the preceding char 1 to many times

`{9}` means  match the preceding char 9 times..so there is no need of using `+` after it

The regex should be

```
/^\d{9}(,\d{9})*$/
```

Comment: Except that in other regular expression engines, `{n}+` creates Possessive matching, which is why it worked in that other tool.  But otherwise, this answer is exactly correct.